# only 8GB diskspace, iCloud keeps downloading iCloud stuff!!! help!

Tags: mac, icloud, disk-space

- Macbook: 128GB - 8GB free
- iCloud: 200GB - 160GB free

I have a very frustrating problem. I have a 128GB Macbook so you can imagine how space is an issue. I bought 200GB iCloud storage thinking that would copy non-essential stuff to iCloud and free up space. I have PLENTY of iCloud storage left but it is no comfort because it does nothing to keep my MacBook free. It seems to keep about 8GB free.. which isn't quite enough to even download a new Xcode version.

I nearly bricked my MacBook by downloading a Mac osX update and it getting stuck half way through with "low disk space" issues.

Searching for large files shows these "iCloud Synchronization files" on my hard drive taking up valuable space!! But I can't unsync them and keep the file in the cloud. It appears I have no control over whats synced.

Is there a setting somewhere that says "try keep xGB free"? Or is there at least an "unsync" command on a synced iCloud file?

Comment: System Prefs>iCloud>Optimise Mac Storage. That's all there is. iCloud is not designed as real storage, only as a data synchroniser between iDevices.

Comment: Yeah I've got optimize Mac storage on - it keeps about 3-4GB of iCloud files cached on my Mac that I don't know how to remove!

Comment: tbh, you need another drive. The general rule about keeping 10% of free space on a drive doesn't really work when the drive is truly teeny. You really ought to be keeping 20 - 30 GB free at all times.

Comment: What do you mean "general rule". I would love to keep 12.8GB free but every time I delete something, iCloud downloads more!!

Comment: It's a massive topic. This seems to cover it well - https://superuser.com/questions/1256074/how-much-space-to-leave-free-on-hdd-or-ssd

Comment: I had to turn off iCloud Drive just so I could download Xcode. This is a joke

Comment: Unfortunately, many people are in the same boat - they bought laptops with teeny non-replaceable SSDs & now the prices for SSD has plummeted, they're stuck until they upgrade their computer next time. A lot of people have bought large iCloud space, thinking they could use it as storage.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the size of my SSD, I mostly use this laptop for coding - with all other big stuff on iCloud. This is perfectly rational setup and the reason one buys iCloud Drive in the first place. The problem is that iCloud keeps filing up the space. I can leave 30 GB free, and iCloud Drive trickles away and downloads up to 8GB free again. This is an iCloud Drive bug.

Comment: iCloud can only re-fill the drive with things you have put there. It's not making up new data to return to your drive. Your issue is your drive is too small for the amount of data you are trying to store. **iCloud is not storage** it is synchronisation, as mentioned in my first comment. If you need more storage get a bigger drive.

Comment: "iCloud can only re-fill the drive with things you have put there"..
I suspect you are being deliberately obtuse, because you appear to be intelligent. If I put things on a drive, I put them on THAT drive, not simultaneously on my other drives - and especially not the small ones which necessitated the purchase of iCloud storage to begin with. There is no gaslightling in the world you can do to try convince anyone that iCloud filling up my drive until 8GB are left is somehow my fault.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me is to turn OFF the `Optimize` setting (see image). It seemingly stopped filling up the harddrive after I changed that setting.

[image]

Comment: Is this still working for you? I just set up a new MacBook and when I untick this it starts downloading everything.