# Prevent iCloud Drive From Auto-Downloading on Mac

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, data-transfer

Is there a way to stop the auto-downloading of files in iCloud Drive on Mac, and if so, how? I want the files synced with iCloud Drive, but I don’t want all the files automatically downloaded. I also don’t want to have to completely turn off iCloud Drive on my Mac to prevent this behavior obviously. I don’t know why it auto-downloads files uploaded to iCloud Drive on the Mac, but not the iPhone. This behavior is really annoying especially when you only have a 128GB Mac and you have to constantly manually remove the downloaded files. Any tips on what to do here would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386785/only-8gb-diskspace-icloud-keeps-downloading-icloud-stuff-help?rq=1

Comment: I think it might. I'll follow the advice on that post and see if it makes any difference. Looked at other pieces of advice on here about this topic and never saw that suggestion, so hopefully it'll work. Thanks for linking to that!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, iCloud Drive will try and download the complete iCloud contents. Unlike Dropbox you can't be selective about what is synced. The suggested link from @DavidSupportsMonica suggests not ticking "Optimise Mac Storage". I think this is good advice as you can then manage space in iCloud and your Mac independently.